# why next version neo4j-mobile-android is not release?

Tags: android, neo4j

Here is first version of neo4j-mobile-android and it released in 2013? 
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-mobile-android
Why that project haven't next version?
thank you with all of my respect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was never really "released" afaik. Read http://neo4j.com/blog/new-incubator-project-neo4j-mobile-for-android-v0-1/ for a write-up. I don't think the project ever went anywhere, as there was no real technical or business justification to do it...

What are you looking to do? What use case? Most people just connect their android system to a server-side application that uses Neo4j as the backend db...

Rik